# jquery tooltip not working on text input

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I'm using the jQuery tooltip available on this website

```
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip
```

and it's working fine using this code

```
$("input[title]").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
```

This should apply the tooltip to any element that has a `title` tag

This is working fine for buttons, images, etc. but when I try it with textboxes, the tooltip only appears if I actually click inside the textbox, any ideas why I'm seeing this behaviour?

Comment: "This should apply the tooltip to any element that has a title tag". Nope. This applies the plugin to any input element (and your use of [title] seems strange to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's default behavior - http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

```
events: {
  def:     "mouseover,mouseout",
  input:   "focus,blur",
  widget:  "focus mouseover,blur mouseout",
  tooltip: "mouseover,mouseout"
}
```

You can change this behavior using events management: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html#events

```
$("element").tooltip({
    events: {
        input: 'mouseover,mouseout'
    }
});
```